# ASP.NET MVC When I Publish There is Missing Folder and Images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, publish

I want to publish my web site that I have made in ASP.NET MVC but when I try to publish, the project can't publish my "Upload" folder. The strange thing is program does not give any error. Any ideas?

[image: Upload folder can't publish]

Comment: Have you using option "All files in this project folder" when publishing? If it's true, set "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy Always" & "Build Action" to "Content" for all files inside that "Upload" folder by using properties window, then try republish your project again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish will not create empty files. Instead, you need to grant read / write and delete permissions for that folder and user only if the empty folder is over the plesk panel.